# Integrating email server authentication with Bugzilla

Tags: php, bugzilla

I am seeking advice from the people here. Is there a way where I can integrate bugzilla authentication using my SMTP server? For instance at bugzilla login user enters email address and the password that ties to the email server authentication and bugzilla makes a smtp connection to test if authentication is successful. When authentication is successful, bugzilla dashboard is shown. Does bugzilla provide such? And, how can I go about doing this?

Comment: What does Bugzilla's documentation say?

Comment: There is no documentation related to this. That is why I am here to ask :-)

Comment: There is no documentation related to the authorization framework in Bugzilla? Em...

Comment: Not that I know. Becoz, I was browsing the manual and I don't see any documentation on email server auth.

Comment: Bugzilla offers PAM integration. That should allow every strategy of authorization you can imagine. I am pretty certain that there are PAM modules authenticating against an SMTP server as authority.

Comment: Yes I have read that line. But I don't see any documentation on how to do so.

Comment: Ah, sorry, took a while to remember what I did to get this to work some 10 years ago... You can use PAM on apache authentication level. Then forward the authenticated credentials to bugzilla as described in the bugzilla documentation. A simple glue between apache and PAM is the `pwauth` package: https://github.com/phokz/pwauth/tree/master/pwauth

Comment: You have tagged this as PHP. You do realize that Bugzilla is written in perl, right? Is there more to the story?